# Rails cache_store with memcached or redis does not produce performace boost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, memcached, benchmarking

I'm playing with Rails' cache. My changes were in the development.rb in the following order:

1. config.cache_store = :file_store, "#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache"
2. config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { :namespace => 'pinukimmm', :expires_in => 1.day, :compress => true }
3. config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }

:file_store gave significant boost from no cache. About 900% increase. But then I changed to memcached with :dalli_store and the performance even slightly dropped, which was unexpected. Then I thought there might be a problem with this store, so I tried :redis_store. Same results.

What could go wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's nothing wrong with it. It's just so with small cache elements. But it scales really well with bigger data.